# Applying magnetic field to magnetite

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I’m an undergrad whose not actually studied this content yet in a lecture series but I'm doing an experiment and I am confused on a result. So, the basic idea is, I heated and then cooled bulk magnetite between 105K - 130K without a magnetic field and did the same with a magnetic field of 1T (10,000 Oe). I obtained current and resistance against Temperature graphs. I found that it actually made no difference to the Verwey Temperature if the magnetic field was there or not. Why is this? Also is the Verwey temperature dependent on B?

I do believe that the magnetic field is perpendicular to the current flow as my lecturer said 'B field is perpendicular to current flow but out of plane rather than in plane perpendicular'. Which is a bit of a confusing way to put it but hopefully the effect I'm seeing will confirm this.